# Unity 3d: Fog not correctly behaving with an object?

Tags: unity-game-engine

First of all, I'd like to thank you a lot for anyone able to help me fixing my problem.

The title itself doesn't explain much but the videos should be enough.

Correct behavior: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/Q8PNefxR0To
Wrong behavior: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/IPNcdxXGPVY

This behavior happens with Unity > 2020.1.x. I need to switch the Unity version for multiple reasons, including compilation errors due to my plugin requirements.
This doesn't happen when I use Windows configuration but when I switch to Android, yes!

As you can see, this problem affects only the "platform" object and behaves correctly with all other objects from what I can see on the scene and simulator so far.
Meaning this is very unlikely coming from fog or lightning general setting but rather from this particular object.
I have thoughtfully inspected what could cause this issue. I asked GPT 4 with different approaches, even asked it to write me a custom shader still giving the same result whatsoever.

Share your thoughts.
Thanks